# How do we access the value pointed by a C pointer in C#?

Tags: c#, marshalling

In my C# application I have `IntPtr y = VoidPointer(x);` where VoidPointer(x) is an unmanaged function that returns a void*(void pointer). The problem is I am not getting the correct value pointed by y in the C# code. I am using `Marshal.ReadInt32(y)` and have tried `ReadByte`, `ReadInt64` etc.  Below are the code snippets,

Unmanaged function in C:

```
void* VoidPointer()
{
    int Var1 = 7113;
    return &Var1;
}
```

Managed function in C# :(using DllImport to access the unmanaged function.)

```
IntPtr z = VoidPointer();

Console.WriteLine(" z = {0} ", Marshal.ReadInt32(z));
```

But in the output I am not getting 7113. How can I access the correct value of Var1 in C# ?

Comment: as per Henrik's answer and subsequent comments, try defining the C integer as static and try again with the code you posted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`VoidPointer` returns a pointer to local variable which goes out of scope when the function ends. This is undefined behavior.

Try declaring Var1 as static:

```
void* VoidPointer()
{
    static int Var1 = 7113;
    return &Var1;
}
```

Comment: Argghh, should have read your answer completely before posting the same thing ;P +1

Comment: @Henrik if the OP were to define it in static scope, would the code he is currently using work?

Comment: @Henrik: +1, I suggest you to include that it will work if it was a static variable in your answer.